# Using npm imports in react-native

Tags: react-native, npm

For example, I use:

```
import geolib from 'geolib'; //actual library
```

How do I access its methods, for example,

```
geolib.getDistance(param1, param2)
```

to use in my rendering? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(geolib.getDistance(param1, param2))`? Are you making sure param1 and param2 are formed correctly? e.g. `{latitude: 51.5103, longitude: 7.49347}`

Comment: have you run `npm install geolib` in your project's directory?

Comment: Is this a question relating to React as appose to the `geolib` library?

Answer (score 1):

`npm install geolib --save` - install module

`import * as geolib from 'geolib'` have you tried importing this way?

Answer (score 0):

Install dependencies

```
npm install --save geolib
```

import in this way

```
const geolib = require('geolib');
```